# Unable to get results php mysqli select with bind

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am attempting to return a result set from mysql in php using mysqli. I have attempted several different ways, but they either end in errors, or empty arrays being returned. I know the query is good because I can run it in my db admin client replacing the question mark with the string needed and it returns as expected. Does anyone see something I have missed? Looks like it should be working to me, but obviously something has to be wrong. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

```
<?php

class db extends mysqli{

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct(PUBP_HOST, PUBP_USER, PUBP_PASS, PUBP_DB);

    }


   /* 
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
   function read_agency_phones($agency_in){

        $returnArray = array();

        if($stmt = $this->prepare("SELECT firstname, lastname, agency, phonenumber FROM employees WHERE agency = ?")){

            try{

                $stmt->bind_param('s', $agency_in);
                $stmt->execute();
                $stmt->bind_result($first, $last, $agency, $phone);



                while($stmt->fetch()){

                    $returnArray[] = array(
                        'first_name'    => $first,
                        'last_name'     => $last,
                        'agency'        => $agency,
                        'phonenumber'   => $phone
                    );

                }

                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();

                return $returnArray;

            } catch (Exception $ex) {

                return $ex->getMessage();

            }

        }

        return 'failed001';


   }

}


$db = new db();

$results = $db->read_agency_phones("SOME_STRING");



echo '<pre>';
echo var_export($results, true);
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

The `agency` field in the database is of type VARCHAR(10).

When running the following query in admin panel, results are returned as expected:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, agency, phonenumber FROM employees WHERE agency = "THE-AGENCY"
```

Comment: Why not just use [fetch_all](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) instead of creating your own array?

Comment: Also, sound like you've made several attempts. What's the problem with this specific version (since that's all we have to go on)? Errors? If so , what errors? Or an empty array? Have you verified that `$agency_in` contains a valid value?

Comment: @ADyson. No errors, empty array, query works fine when executed in admin console replacing `?` with needed string. Updated code to be more clear about what I'm doing.

Comment: You didn't answer my question about whether `$agency_in` contains the necessary value. If replacing it manually in your DB client works, then the difference is quite likely to be that this variable does not contain what you think it does. You can check its contents easily using var_dump or similar just before the query executes.

Comment: @ADyson I copy the value straight from the php code and paste it into the query in the admin panel. It's identical. I'm attempting to enable mysql query log to see the exact query being executed. Something has to be messed up somewhere.

Comment: OK. What is the data type of the "agency" field in your DB? String (varchar) or int, or what? When you bind the parameter, you're telling it to be interpreted by the DB as a string (this is regardless of what PHP might think it is). But if the DB field is something numeric, the WHERE clause will never match anything when you run the query from PHP. That could be a possible difference to the query in the admin panel. What _exactly_ do you run in the admin panel? Paste an example here please, for comparison. And some sample data that you do/don't expect back as a result would be useful too.

Comment: @ADyson updated question to contain query being ran in admin panel and datatype of agency column

Comment: And you are sure when you run your PHP that the value of `$agency_in` is also `"THE-AGENCY"`? And (stupid question but has to be asked) that your PHP app connects to the same database as your admin panel? Because it's difficult to see what else could be the problem.

Comment: @ADyson. I am sure. So sure that I moved this exact code into production (since it didn't affect the rest of the system), and everything works as expected. Whatever is going must have something to do with php/msyqli functionality on my local development machine. Glad to know I'm not going crazy, but still curious as to what's going on with my machine. I'll have to dig in deeper, but for now the crisis has been averted.

Comment: I'd still put money on it being different databases :-). Let me know if you find out. Glad you managed to avert the immediate issue though.